# OpenCV using CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2

Tags: opencv, video-capture

Question 1: What are the difference between the following two methods in CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    //get the frame from the camera
    currentFrame = inputFrame.rgba();

...
    return outputFrame;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {

    inputFrame.copyTo(current);
    ...
    return outputFrame;
}
```

Question 2: When grabbing a frame using JavaCameraView javaCameraView (Opencv), which one is correct

Option 1:

```
currentFrame = inputFrame.rgba();
```

Option 2:

```
inputFrame.copyTo(currentFrame);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Option 1:
>
> currentFrame = inputFrame.rgba();

Here `inputFrame` is an [interface](https://iopencv.com/docs/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame.html) that contains a frame being returned from `CameraBrideViewBase` camera interaction. The `.rgba()` method then returns the opencv type [Mat](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a33fd5d125b4c302b0c9aa86980791a77) containing image information.

> Option 2:
>
> inputFrame.copyTo(currentFrame);

Here inputFrame is an instance of the opencv type `Mat`

The confusion in original question arises because of the similar signature of the method **public Mat onCameraFrame( name)**. The method in *Option 1* is member of `CvCameraViewListener2` interface and the method in *Option 2* is part of the `CvCameraViewListener` interface.

The [docs](https://iopencv.com/docs/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.html) issue caution for the `CvCameraViewListener` interface

> Attention: Do not use objects, that represents this interface out of
> onCameraFrame callback!